# GPG Sub Key Renewal Questions

Tags: public-key, keys, pgp, smartcard

Last year, I followed [this guide](https://wiki.bootc.net/gnupg/generating-keys.html#getting-started-and-requirements) to create two GnuPG Smart Cards; one card with the Primary Key and the other card with the Sub-keys.

I noticed that the sub keys were close to expiring so I renewed them and sent them to the sub-key Smart Card and saved the new luks image back to a USB.

My questions are:

1. What is the proper way to update the sub-keys on a keyserver? Apparently, the key that I uploaded to http://pgp.mit.edu has the Primary key's ID but shows the sub-keys with the old expiration date.
2. Will I be able to decrypt anything that was encrypted with the old sub-keys? Or use any of the other functions from the old sub-keys (Sign, Encrypt, Authenticate)?

I ask #2 because I was using the sub-key card for SSH Authentication and had to re-run `ssh-copy-id` for each server. I noticed the output of `ssh-add -L` had different output as well.

Thankfully, I haven't encrypted anything important with the old sub-keys but I was hoping to understand the process before committing to using it.

I'm running Debian 9.5 (Stretch) with gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.18.